# How can I fix with Cleditor on the size

Tags: javascript, jquery, text-editor, cleditor

I've searched for the solution for this everywhere and have not found an answer

There is a problem with cleditor on the size (when change size browser).
Fields will be lost. Must press reload again. 
So that data back.

When you click on the toolbar to display the error.

> error executing the justify center command.

[image]

How can I fix it.

Thank you